# Deselection fabric.js object event

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to execute some code every time a specific fabric object is "deselected". Is there any deselection event I can handle? I already have a function for when the object is selected, via the selected event, but have not found any documentation about the deselected one. At the canvas level I have the selection:cleared and selection:created events, but nothing for the deselection either.

Cheers,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 16):

Use the `before:selection:cleared` event and get the active object or group. After that you can check if it corresponds to your specific fabric object.

```
canvas.on('before:selection:cleared', function() {
    var clearedObject;
    if(typeof(canvas.getActiveObject()) !== 'undefined') {
        clearedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    }
    else {
        clearedObject = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    }
    //do stuff with the deselected element if it is the specific one you want.
});
```

Comment: There is a small typo in line 3, the closing bracket should be after the .getActiveObject() call.
Also, there is a missing ")" in the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Just to let you all know that the newest versions of [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) include a `deselected` event for the [Object class](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html). The only thing you need to do now is:

```
var aFabricObject = <create your fabric object>

aFabricObject.on('deselected', function (options) {
     // your code here
});
```

Comment: This is mentioned in the document too but somehow it is not firing when the object is deselected !

Answer (score 0):

Update for the upper [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42157762/9477553):
The 'deselected' event fires a async method, so you can not get 'options.deselected' immediately.

```
var aFabricObject = <create your fabric object>

aFabricObject.on('deselected', function (options) {
  console.log(options.deselected) // output undefined
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(options.deselected) // output the correct target
  }, 0)
});
```